# mysql - Update value in column, while making all others false

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to set some options to be active/inactive and I'm using a column called `active` which will either be 1 or 0.

Is there a better way to make all 0 except one which will equal 1 and be determined by form submission besides running two queries?

Right now I have this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE customizer SET active='1' WHERE text_color='{$text_color}'");
```

But eventually they'll all be 1.

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*` functions. These API is deprecated. Also use prepared Statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE `customizer` SET `active` = (`text_color` = '{$text_color}')
```

Performs a comparison, which returns `1` if true, `0` if false, and puts that result in the `active` column.

Consider changing your database structure, though. It would be much better for consistency to have `active_colour` saved with your user data or something.

Comment: That was perfect, thank you. I've never used that syntax before. Good to know :)